# Proving a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

Let $\Bbb R [x]$ denote the group of all polynomials with real coefficients, under the operation of addition. Let $\psi : \Bbb R[x] \to \Bbb R$ be the function defined by $\psi (p(x)) = p(3)$, for all $p(x) \in \Bbb R [x]$.

I'm trying to prove this to be a group homomorphism and so far this is what I got...

Proof:
First, we must show that $\psi (p(x+y)) = \psi (p(x)) + \psi (p(y))$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$. Therefore, $(x+y)(3) = 3x + 3y = \psi (p(x)) + \psi (p(y)) = \psi (p(x+y))$, proving that $\psi$ is a group homomorphism.

Just wondering if I have everything I need in this proof for it to be correct.

Comment: No this is not correct. You are assuming $p(x)=x$ and $p(y)=y$, which is not valid. Also, if $p(x)=x$, then $p(3)$ is $3$, not $x$.

Comment: Also, what you need to show is $\psi(p(x)+p(y))=\psi(p(x))+\psi(p(y))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re trying to prove the wrong thing. What you must prove is that if $p,q\in\Bbb R[x]$ (i.e., $p$ and $q$ are polynomials in the indeterminate $x$ with real coefficients), then $$\psi(p+q)=\psi(p)+\psi(q)\;.$$ And this is true:

$$\begin{align*}
\psi(p+q)&=(p+q)(3)\\
&=p(3)+q(3)\\
&=\psi(p)+\psi(q)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Why do you need to show that $\psi(-p)=-\psi(p)$? OP said they just need to show it is a group homomorphism

Comment: @NicholasRoberts: You’re right, of course; it clearly comes for free.